# How to set multiple value in selectize input?

Tags: javascript, html, selectize.js

I try some solution but didn't work

```
<input id="select1" name="select1" type="text" class="select1 demo-default"/>

var $select = $("#select1").selectize();
var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
selectize.setValue(["test1","test2"]);`
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail as to exactly what you are trying to do? Selectize.js can do a variety of things, so some clarity would help. Are you trying to have test1 and test2 as values in the generated drop-down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Selectize</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.default.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<input type="text" id="input-tags1" class="demo-default test">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>


<script>
var $select = $('.demo-default').selectize({
persist: false,
createOnBlur: true,
create: true,

});

var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
selectize.addOption([{text: "puja", value: "puja"}, {text: "raxit", value: "raxit"},]);
selectize.setValue(['puja','raxit']);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```